# Magento: How to include a php call in the CMS pages

Tags: php, magento, call

Following the instructions from this page:

http://www.magento.cc/how-to-use-php-on-a-cms-page.html

1) i declared the module in the *app/etc/modules* :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stock_status>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
</Stock_status>
</modules>
</config>
```

2) Then i created the **config.xml** in *app\code\local\Stock\status\Custom\etc* with these contents in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
<blocks>
<Stock_status>
<class>Stock_status_Block</class>
</Stock_status>
</blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

3) afterwards i created a **test.php** in *app/code/local/Stock/status/Custom/Block* file with these contents in it:

```
<?php
class Stock_status_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
protected function _toHtml()
{
.Mage::helper('customstockstatus')->getListStatus($_product->getId()).
return $html;
}
}
```

and finally 
4) i went in a cms page to see if it works by putting this value in:

```
{{block type="Stock_status_Custom/test" ListStatus="02"}}
```

This line of code should return me the stock status of a specific product (in this example, the product with the ID 02)

BUT it doesn't work. What have i done incorrectly? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are an unnecessary works, you can simply call the php file by adding the following line into that cms page content

```
   {{block type="core/template" template="page/urfile.phtml"}}
```

Then create file under the page directory

Comment: This would return me the php page. It is not what i am looking for. What i want to do is get the stock status of a specific product right from the CMS block. For example when i put this code <?php echo Mage::helper('customstockstatus')->getListStatus(01); ?> in a php file, it gives me the stock status of product with the ID 01. I want to do the same thing from the CMS block

Answer (score -1):

go to Magento Admin->CMS->Pages

1. Click Add New Page
2. Input Page Title
3. Input URL Key
4. Right Content inside (body)
5. paste your code.

Hope this help

Comment: If i put directly the code <?php echo Mage::helper('stockstatus')->getListStatus(01); ?> in the CMS pages, the code is not being rendered.

Comment: Magento CMS page can't rendered php tag directly