# PHP Code in Magento CMS Page Not Rendering With Custom Template

Tags: php, html, magento, content-management-system

I'm trying to use some PHP on a CMS page in Magento. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144908/magento-how-to-include-a-php-call-in-the-cms-pages) - but had no luck. When I check it, the html is there, but it doesn't execute the php code.

I created the file `featured_solutions.phtml` in the page directory. Here are the contents of that file

```
<h2>Featured Solutions</h2>

<p>Our Featured VoIP Solutions are selected by our experienced engineers to be Industry leading technologies that you’ll want to consider when choosing the best VoIP solution for your business or customers.</p>

<p>With in-depth VoIP product overviews and reviews, tutorials and videos, our Featured VoIP Solutions will advise you on what VoIP equipment to use, how to implement it, and why you should choose it.</p>

<div class="featured-solutions">
<?php
    $directory="/skin/frontend/default/ultimento-custom/images/featured";
    $featured_images = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir ($directory));
    $count=1;

    foreach ($featured_images as $feat){
        $feat_solution = basename($feat, ".png");
        if($count % 3 == 0) { ?>
        <div class="featured-right">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="featured-left">
        <?php }
        echo '<a class="featured" href="../featured-solution/'.$feat_solution.'">
              <img src="/skin/frontend/default/ultimento-custom/images/featured/'.$feat.'" class="img-featured" />
              <p>Featured Solution: '.$feat_solution.'</p>
              </a>
              </div>';

        $count++;
    }
?>    
</div>
```

Then in my CMS page, I have this line

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/featured_solutions.phtml"}}
```

The result is, the html is executed, but not the PHP. Anything inside the  tags does not show up.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you add some wrong php code for debug, e.g. `var_dump($featured_images); ff();` after the `$featured_images = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir ($directory));`. If this code will execute you will know it and you will know how many files in еру variable `$featured_images`

Comment: @AleksandrIvashchenko i just tried this and i get NULL under my html. also the rest of the page doesn't load

Comment: It's good, because function `ff()` is undefined and you got fatal error but you saw `NULL` it means that `preg_grep` did not return any results maybe you use wrong path. Firt of all I recomended add `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1` to `.htaccess` if you want to debug and the next step is debug results of `scandir`. Add line `var_dump(scandir($directory)); ff();` before `$featured_images = preg_grep ...` and fix variable `$directory` you forgot a dot before the first slash `$directory="./skin/frontend`

Comment: @AleksandrIvashchenko ugh of course that was it, i forgot the . before the first slash. thanks for pointing that out. seems to be all good now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AleksandrIvashchenko pointed out I was missing a . before my first / in my $directory